# Can't load simple JSON string in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to retrieve some data from the FaceBook graph API. The API URL returns the following string:

```
access_token=AAABBBB&expires=5173539
```

The following Python code throws a `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded` on the 4th line:

```
import json
import urllib2
data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
jdata = json.loads(data)
print jdata.access_token
```

Comment: What makes you think the string "access_token=AAABBBB&expires=5173539" is JSON encoded?

Comment: S. Lott- Nothing - I don't know what what I was thinking

Comment: Neither do we.  Perhaps you should delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the actual body of the API response:

```
access_token=AAABBBB&expires=5173539
```

That's not JSON.  It's just a query string, much like a GET request, and will need to be parsed in another way.

Comment: Casey- thank you for pointing out the embarrassingly obvious- my bad